# Gradle 3.0.0 (in Android Studio 3.0) reorder the tasks sequence (when compile with Kotlin module)?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I have a simple gradle script (just to log when my Gradle task is run)

```
    class TestScriptTask extends DefaultTask {
        @TaskAction
        def testScript() {
            logger.quiet("My Gradle Task Here")
        }
    }

    project(":app") {
        task testScript(type: TestScriptTask) {
        }
    }
```

And I have a simple Android project, "app" which is dependent on a module "remotelib" in Kotlin.

My app's build.gradle dependencies as below

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':remotelib')
    // and others
}
```

So when I run my gradle tasks as below

```
 ./gradlew :app:assembleRelease :app:testScript
```

The script is run as below (note the Task Here is executed first)

```
> Task :app:testScript
My Gradle Task Here

> Task :remotelib:compileReleaseKotlin
Using kotlin incremental compilation
```

This only happens beginning using `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'` (as well as `beta2`).

When I was on `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'`, the sequence is okay, as expected i.e.

```
> Task :remotelib:compileReleaseKotlin
Using kotlin incremental compilation

> Task :app:testScript
My Gradle Task Here
```

Is this a gradle 3.0.0 bug, or a new way of handling the task order?

**Update**

My project wide build.gradle as below

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
}

apply from: 'test_script.gradle'


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir

}
```

Comment: There's a lot of changes in the Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0 and its interoperation with the Kotlin plugin, and the changes might also include some that affect the tasks ordering. However, in your example, you don't specify (at least in the code posted here) that your `:app:testScript` task depends on Kotlin compilation in `remotelib`. It could be done with either a `dependsOn` relationship or by using the `compile` configuration of `app` as an input for the `testScript` task. Otherwise, the execution order between these two tasks is undefined, and they can be run in an arbitrary order.

Comment: Thanks @hotkey. Can you show me how to make `:app:testScript task depends on Kotlin compilation in remotelib`? Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I've described how it could be done in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of changes in the Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0 and its interoperation with the Kotlin plugin, and the changes might also include some that affect the tasks ordering.

However, in your example, you don't specify (at least in the code posted here) that your `:app:testScript` task depends on Kotlin compilation in `:remotelib`. Therefore the execution order between these two tasks is undefined, and they can be run in an arbitrary order.

This could be done by one of the following:

- `testScript.dependsOn configurations.compile`

  Since you have added `compile project(':remotelib')` to the dependencies of `app`, making `testScript` depend on `configurations.compile` will also trigger the build of the default configuration in the project `:remotelib`, thus also compiling Kotlin in it.
- `testScript.dependsOn project(':remotelib').compileKotlin`

  This explicitly specifies that the task depends on `:remotelib:compileKotlin`, but it requires `:remotelib` to be evaluated before `:app` (you may need to add the `evaluationDependsOn ':remotelib'` line to your `:app`'s build script).

Comment: The above `TestScriptTask` is all reside within a file `test_script.gradle`. And in the project `build.gradle`, I call `apply from: 'test_script.gradle'`. I try to apply your propose `testScript.dependsOn configurations.compile` in the app `build.gradle`, or even in `test_script.gradle`... but keep getting error. Where should I place your propose script above?

Comment: @Elye, what is the error you are getting? Basically, either solution I suggested in the answer should be applied *after* the `testScript` task is created. That is, after `apply from: ... ` in `build.gradle` or after the task definition in `test_script.gradle`.

Comment: I get this error `Could not get unknown property 'testScript' for root project 'MyApplication' of type org.gradle.api.Project.` I add it right after the line of `apply from: 'test_script.gradle'` as shown in my update above.

Comment: Acually, you can wrap either of the lines I suggested into an `afterEvaluate { ... }` block to make it run only after the build script has been evaluated. The error you are getting tells you that, at the moment when the line gets executed, the task `testScript` has not yet been created. So, you need to execute it later.

Comment: I have put it in my `test_script.gradle`'s `project(":app")` scope. I could do `./gradlew clean` without issue. But when run `./gradlew assemble`, it error out with `Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:testScript'. Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:compile'. Could not resolve project :remotelib.... `

Comment: Got it compiled, as I change `compile` to `implementation`. Everything goes through. However, the testScript is still executed first before kotlin compile :(

Comment: I got it working, by adding `testScript.dependsOn assemble` in my app's build.gradle. It's a good workaround. However, I think it should preserve the order of the command line given. As stated in https://docs.gradle.org/0.9-rc-2/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html, `Gradle will execute the tasks in the order that they are listed on the command-line`